# FFMPEG FishEye Equirectangular

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, streaming, 360-virtual-reality

I'm struggling with FFMPEGs Remap Filter.  I have a security camera that streams a bunch of different options, but the default is this FishEye:
[image]

I see a TON of maps for Ricotah Theta's, but nothing that shows me how to generate those map files for a different layout, like the one I have.  I've tried doing just 2 pano's, but the image gets stretched out so much when I stream to YouTube.  Can someone point me in the right direction???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making this far too difficult.  Just send youtube the fisheye using FFMPEG.  You can tweak the size to prevent some of the distortion.

Answer (score 1):

You posted a modified imaged (cropped and moved), so applying ffmpeg directly gives weird results, but with raw images, which probably look like this...

[image: original fisheye]

using this command...

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vf v360=fisheye:e:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=-90 -y output.jpg
```

you would get this result:
[image: result]

You can then view it here: https://renderstuff.com/tools/360-panorama-web-viewer/

Answer (score 0):

You need the [v360](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360) filter. Make sure you use the latest ffmpeg build; older versions don't include this filter.

I used these parameters for a security camera:

```
-vf v360=fisheye:equirect:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180
```

Result:
[image: equirectangular result]

You might want to crop the video (because of the black margins):

```
-vf crop=1500:1500:250:0,v360=fisheye:equirect:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180,crop=1500:1500:750:0
```

Of course, adjust the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter parameters to your situation.